# How to capture self because calling super.init?

Tags: swift

How to capture self because calling super.init?

```
public class Var<T> {
    let _get : Void -> T
    init(_ f : Void -> T) {
        _get = f
    }
    public var value : T {
        get {
            return _get()
        }
    }
}

public class Value<T> : Var<T> {
    var _val : T
    public init(_ t: T) {
        _val = t
        super.init({ [unowned self] in self._val })  // <--- Error
    }
}
```

Error:

```
error: 'self' used before super.init call
    super.init({ [unowned self] in self._val })
```

---

I know I can override getter but it is irrelevant in this question

Comment: It's not possible - `self` is unavailable until all class properties have been initialized (including the inherited ones).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class Value<T> : Var<T> {
    var _val : T
    public init(_ t: T) {
        _val = t
        var v:(()->T)!
        super.init({ v() })
        v = { [unowned self] in self._val }
    }
}
```

OR

```
public class Value<T> : Var<T> {
    var _val : T
    public init(_ t: T) {
        _val = t
        weak var _self:Value<T>!
        super.init({ _self._val })
        _self = self
    }
}
```